# Python Django Cannot go the wanted link within another page

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on a website and I have a navigation bar in it. When I click the "about" button I need website to open `localhost:8000/about/` link. But when I'm in a different page like `localhost:8000/chapter/3/` It directs me to `localhost:8000/chapter/3/about/` (The website is about a web novel thats why there is chapters) How can I make it so that wherever I click that "about" button from I want it to direct me to `localhost:8000/about/`. How can I make it happen?

**Urls:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('chapter/<int:cid>/', views.view, name="chapter"),
    path('chapter/<int:cid>', views.view, name="chapter"),
    path('about/', views.about, name="about_us")
]
```

**Views:**

```
def home(request):
    chapter_list = Chapter.objects.all()
    last = chapter_list.last()
    return render(request, 'main.html',
                  {'chapter_list': chapter_list,
                  'last': last})


def view(request, cid: int):
    chapter_info = Chapter.objects.get(chapter_id=cid)
    chapter_info.chapter_text = chapter_info.chapter_text.replace('background-color:#ffffff', '')
    chapter_info.chapter_text = chapter_info.chapter_text.replace('color:#757575', 'color:#EEEEE')
    chapter_info.chapter_footnotes = chapter_info.chapter_footnotes.replace('background-color:#ffffff', '')
    chapter_info.chapter_footnotes = chapter_info.chapter_footnotes.replace('color:#757575', 'color:#EEEEE')
    return render(request, 'chapters.html', {'chapter_info': chapter_info})


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html', {})
```

**Note:**
I tried using ../ but didn't work for me

Comment: `Assume that urls and views are properly set up`, but they aren't. Please post what your actual `urls.py` file looks like.

Comment: @HampusLarsson added urls.py and views.py to the question

Comment: can you add your html page to the above question where you adding about link

Comment: <li><a href="about">About</a></li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this where ever you are it will got the about link. Try reading absolute and relative path.

```
<a href="/about">about</a>
```